# Need to extract only those digits which are having 5 to 6 digit length

Tags: r, regex

I need to extract only 5 or 6 digit from a string. For example "hi 23456678 is number, also there is a number 92844 and 741653 "
I need to extract only the 5 or 6 digit number from string , i tried \d{5,6} but it is giving me result as (23456, 92844, 741653) but my desired outcome should be only 92844 & 741653 , how can i get that.
I am using R, please suggest.

Comment: What about `\d{5,6}(\D|$)`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
^[0-9]{5,6}$
```

{5,6} = between 5 and 6 characters